# compareTo() in two different classes, one not reachable

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I have two different classes with two different `compareTo()`-methods. When I sort the `list`, I would like it to first sort by `age`. But if it's two Fysiker getting sorted, and their ages are the same, I would like it to then sort on "year", which is the year they started studying.

When I run my main class, I put 80 Fysiker in a list, I sort them, and then I print them. They are all sorted by age, but not by year (if they've got the same age).

Edit1 (why it's not a duplicate):
The reason I can't use `abstract` to solve this (which they have done in the duplicate marked version of this question), is because I need to be able to instantiate a `Human` by writing `Human humantest = new Human()`.

Main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Human> randomFysiker = new ArrayList<Human>();
    for (int j=0;j<80;j++) {

        Fysiker f = new Fysiker();
        randomFysiker.add(f);
}       
    Collections.sort(randomFysiker);

    System.out.println(randomFysiker);
}


}
```

Human class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Human implements Comparable<Human> {

int age;
String name;
List<String> people = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","P");
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

public Human(int myAge, String myName) {
    name = myName;
    age = myAge;
}

public Human() {
    this.age = randomAge();
    this.name = randomName();
        }

public int compareTo(Human o) {
    return this.age - o.age;
}

private int randomAge() {
    return randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
}

protected String randomName() {
    return people.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(people.size()));
}

public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String toString() {
    return "\nName: " + name + "\nAge: " + age + " yrs old\n";
}
}
```

Fysiker class:

```
public class Fysiker extends Human {

private int year;

public Fysiker(int myAgeF, String myNameF, int myYearF) {
    this.name = myNameF;
    this.age = myAgeF;
    this.year = myYearF;
}

public Fysiker() {
    this.name = randomName();
    this.age = randomAge();
    this.year = randomYear();
}

public int compareTo(Fysiker o) {
    if (this.age - o.age != 0) {
        return super.compareTo(o);
    }
    else {
        return this.year - o.year;
    }
}

private int randomAge() {
    return 15 + randomGenerator.nextInt(86);
}

private int randomYear() {
    int yearfifteen = 2015 - age + 15;
    if (yearfifteen >= 1932 && 2015 >= yearfifteen){
        return randomGenerator.nextInt(age-14) + yearfifteen; //(max-min)=(yearfifteen+age-15+1)-(yearfifteen+1)
    }
    else {
        return 1932 + randomGenerator.nextInt(84);
    }
}

public int getYear(){
    return year;
}

public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "Started Physics: " + String.format("F%02d", this.year%100) + "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: change the comparator to the following: public int compareTo(Fysiker o) {
    if (this.age == o.age ) {
        return this.year - o.year;
    }
    else {
        return super.compareTo(o);
    }
}

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz: that doesn't solve the issue of his sort sorting using Human's compareTo, not Fysiker, since the child class's compareTo method is not an override of the currently used interface. I think he'll run into a compilation error if he gives that method an `@Override` annotation.

Comment: yeah, i tried that code, didn't work. also true that I can't use override in this scenario

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I edited my text to explain why I can't use `abstract`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would like to answer this question since I have the solution now, but I can't answer it since it's marked as duplicate. Check my EDIT as to why the solution to the duplicate question doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `compareTo()`-method of `Fysiker` should be changed to;

```
public int compareTo(Human o) {
    if(this.age==o.age && o instanceof Fysiker) {
        return this.year - ((Fysiker)o).year;
    }
    return super.compareTo(o);
}
```

If the two `Human`s have the same age and both are of class `Fysiker`, then they will be sorted by year with this method.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `compareTo()` method of `Fysiker` class to:

```
public int compareTo(Human o) {
    if (this.age - o.age != 0) {
        return super.compareTo(o);
    }
    else {
        return this.year - ((Fysiker)o).year;
    }
}
```

So this will override the superclass method and thus the method of the subclass, i.e. Fysiker, will be called.